# What would prevent actionscript flash from calling a JS object in IE9?

Tags: javascript, flash, internet-explorer, actionscript

Is it possible the JS object object doesn't exist when the flash calls?

Here is all the source and the issue ticket for the SWF project this is happening on: http://code.google.com/p/mp3player/issues/detail?id=43&thanks=43&ts=1329096944

PS - I have the swf mp3 player working with some custom JS that removes the need for the swf to call the JS, but I'd love to understand why IE9 does this while the other browsers work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE9 breaks `ExternalInterface` calls if your flash is embedded in your page with a `<object>` tag with `<embed>` failover.

Using a JavaScript Flash Page Embed library like [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) should resolve this.

Also have a look at this MSDN page for more details: [OBJECT Fallback Is Included in DOM and Matched by window[name]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg622942%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)